# How do I call toString correctly from unknown?

Tags: typescript

I want to write a `function` that will return a `string` from an `unknown` value

Since I can't know what was originally put there, but I want to describe the type correctly, I don't use `any`, I use `unknown`.

But my question is, how to call correctly method `toString` from it?

I don't want `typescript` to complain

[Error when calling a method from unknown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/caAuV.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Instead, edit your question and copy & paste your code into it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found an excerpt from the documentation - [`unknown` isn’t assignable to anything but itself and any without a type assertion or a control flow based narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#new-unknown-top-type)

So instead of using the [.toString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) method, it is better to use the [String()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) class.

Example:

```
export const intoString = (value: unknown) => String(value)
```

In addition I will leave hacks, in my opinion not the best solutions, with different results, but maybe you will be interested in them.

```
function f1(x: unknown) {
  return "" + x
}

function f2(x: unknown) {
  return String(x)
}

function f3(x: unknown) {
  return `${x}`
}

function f4(x: unknown) {
  return typeof (x as any)?.toString === "function" && (x as any)?.toString() || ""
}

function f5(x: unknown) {
  return Object.prototype.toString.call(x);
}

function f6(x: unknown) {
  return (x as any).toString()
}

function f7(x: unknown) {
  return (x as any)?.toString()
}

const cases = {
  undefined,
  null: null,
  symbol: Symbol(),
  "{ valueOf() { return 88 } }": { valueOf() { return 88 } },
  "() => {}": () => {},
  "{ toString() { return 99 } }": { toString() { return 99 } },
  "Object.create(null)": Object.create(null),
}

const res: { [key: string]: { [key: string]: unknown } } = {}

for (const [name, obj] of Object.entries(cases)) {
  const cur: { [key: string]: unknown } = res[name] = {}
  
  for (const f of [f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6, f7]) {
    try {
      cur[f as any] = f(obj)
    } catch (err) {
      cur[f as any] = err
    }
  }
}

console.table(res)
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: `String()` is almost good way, except undefined. `String(undefined) => "undefined"`

Answer (score 2):

Not everything that's `unknown` can have `toString()`:

```js
function foo(input: unknown) {
  if (
    typeof input === 'object' && 
    input !== null && 
    'toString' in input
  ) return input.toString();
}
```

You can change/expand this to support other types.